# Issue with gui designing in java

Tags: java, swing

I m designing a gui which displays an image on a panel and has a slider which zooms the image in and out. But the issue is: My image gets zoomed but does not show the image inside the scrollpane **Scrollpane**.

```
ImagePanel imageP = new ImagePanel("D:/ScannedImage1.jpg");
JSlider slid = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
float value = (float) slid.getValue();
imageP.setScale(value);
imagePanel.add(new JScrollPane(imageP), BorderLayout.CENTER);
imagePanel.validate();
```

code For imagePanel class paintComponent Method

```
super.paintComponent(g);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
int w = getWidth();
int h = getHeight();
int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
double x = (w - scale * imageWidth) / 2;
double y = (h - scale * imageHeight) / 2;
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance (x, y);
at.scale(scale, scale);
g2.drawRenderedImage(image, at);
```

Comment: show us the code for ImagePanel. Your problem is likley to be there or in the imagepath

Comment: He is a new user, perhaps he has asked a lot of questions but they have not yet provided any good (or any at all?) answers?

Comment: Almost all of his questions have been pretty basic with decent enough answers, but only a single accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `JScrollPane` relies on the client's preferred size, you may need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of `ImagePanel` in a way that reflects the zoomed size.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
imageP.add(new JScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
imageP.validate();
```

If not, and you really are trying to call directly from the class, then shouldn't it be:

```
ImagePanel.add(new JScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
ImagePanel.validate();
```

And the add() and validate() methods should be static, otherwise you should use the first example.